# C# | Парсинг сайта с вытягиванием JSON из переменной в <script>

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json, anglesharp

уважаемые знатоки.
Допустим имеется такой html шаблон:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
        <script>
        ...
        var date = {
            mas: [{prm: [{...}, {...}, ...]}, ], ...
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Кто работал уже с этим, подскажите, как можно выдернуть из переменной date JSON? Как я понимаю AngleSharp тут не поможет. Так как он заточен на работу с id, class, css, может это конечно не так. Пока вижу путь через Regex. По типу:

```
string pattern = @"var date = {mas.*}";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
```

Или есть более грамотное решение этому?

Comment: Я бы сделал очень просто: нашел бы первым делом нужный `<script>..</script>` (через XPath например это было бы нечто на подобии `//script[contains(text(),"mas")]`), ну а дальше, этот небольшой кусочек можно просто вытянуть через `.Substring()`, найдя начало строки и ее конец.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://stackoverflow.com/a/57138053/12888024 :) но мне лень писать ответ.

Comment: @aepot Если одна переменная, то может быть, ок, а если там функция ([пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32vk1.png))?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ о, Евгений. Рад вас видеть. Как всегда помогли добрым советом. Диву даюсь сколько у вас практики. Вот бы мне столько набраться, чтоб тоже начать другим помогать. Про XPath еще не слышал - придется мне почитать статейки :) Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, спасибо. Возьму на вооружение :)

Comment: @eugenelly xPath тут как пример, не более, ведь выдернуть элемент можно любыми способами. Вот [например](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9D64k0) через LINQ вытянул нужное (если речь конечно про тот же сайт идет). Да и также `.Substring()` можно заменить кучей других приблуд (хоть Regex, хоть парсеры и т.д.). Короче, задачу можно решить разными способами, я показал, как по мне, самый простой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как говорится, простое решение самое гениальное :) Я бы до такого лаконичного решения еще наверное долго бы сам доходил. Спасибо вам, буду изучать.